# Attaching a dll

Tags: c#, dll, process

I have made a dll, that makes windows 10 notepad customable, and it has a ui, but it needs to be injected. I have made a console injector in c++ and it works flawlessly, but i want a ui for the injector. I tried using CLR but it did not work. So i made this calsses in c# winforms:

`

```
       using System; using System.Diagnostics; using System.Runtime.InteropServices; using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TestUI { public class DllInjector { public bool InjectDll(string processName, int processId, string dllPath) { // Get a handle to the target process IntPtr processHandle = OpenProcess(ProcessAccessFlags.All, false, processId); if (processHandle == IntPtr.Zero) { MessageBox.Show("Failed to get handle to the target process"); return false; }
// Allocate memory in the target process for the DLL path
        IntPtr dllPathAddress = VirtualAllocEx(processHandle, IntPtr.Zero, (uint)dllPath.Length + 1,
            AllocationType.Commit, MemoryProtection.ReadWrite);
        if (dllPathAddress == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Failed to allocate memory in the target process");
            return false;
        }

        // Write the DLL path to the target process
        byte[] dllPathBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(dllPath);
        if (!WriteProcessMemory(processHandle, dllPathAddress, dllPathBytes,
            (uint)dllPathBytes.Length, out _))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Failed to write DLL path to target process");
            return false;
        }

        // Get the address of LoadLibraryA in kernel32.dll
        IntPtr loadLibraryAddress = GetLoadLibraryAddress();
        if (loadLibraryAddress == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Failed to get address of LoadLibraryA");
            return false;
        }

        // Call LoadLibraryA in the target process to load the DLL
        IntPtr remoteThread = CreateRemoteThread(processHandle, IntPtr.Zero, 0, loadLibraryAddress,
            dllPathAddress, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
        if (remoteThread == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Failed to create remote thread in the target process");
            return false;
        }

        // Wait for the remote thread to finish
        WaitForSingleObject(remoteThread, 0xFFFFFFFF);

        // Free the memory allocated in the target process for the DLL path
        VirtualFreeEx(processHandle, dllPathAddress, 0, 0x8000);

        // Close the handle to the target process
        CloseHandle(processHandle);

        return true;
    }

    private static IntPtr GetLoadLibraryAddress()
    {
        // Load kernel32.dll into the current process
        IntPtr kernel32 = LoadLibraryA("kernel32.dll");
        if (kernel32 == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            return IntPtr.Zero;
        }

        // Get the address of LoadLibraryA from kernel32.dll
        IntPtr loadLibraryAddress = GetProcAddress(kernel32, "LoadLibraryA");
        if (loadLibraryAddress == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            return IntPtr.Zero;
        }

        // Free the library handle
        FreeLibrary(kernel32);

        return loadLibraryAddress;
    }

    // Declare the necessary WinAPI functions for injecting the DLL
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(ProcessAccessFlags dwDesiredAccess, bool bInheritHandle, int dwProcessId);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr VirtualAllocEx(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpAddress, uint dwSize,
        AllocationType flAllocationType, MemoryProtection flProtect);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool WriteProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpBaseAddress, byte[] lpBuffer,
        uint nSize, out UIntPtr lpNumberOfBytesWritten);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr CreateRemoteThread(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpThreadAttributes, uint dwStackSize,
     IntPtr lpStartAddress, IntPtr lpParameter, uint dwCreationFlags, IntPtr lpThreadId);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern uint WaitForSingleObject(IntPtr hHandle, uint dwMilliseconds);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool VirtualFreeEx(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpAddress, uint dwSize, uint dwFreeType);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr hObject);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr LoadLibraryA(string lpLibFileName);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr hModule, string lpProcName);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool FreeLibrary(IntPtr hModule);
}

[Flags]
public enum ProcessAccessFlags : uint
{
    All = 0x001F0FFF,
    Terminate = 0x00000001,
    CreateThread = 0x00000002,
    VirtualMemoryOperation = 0x00000008,
    VirtualMemoryRead = 0x00000010,
    VirtualMemoryWrite = 0x00000020,
    DuplicateHandle = 0x00000040,
    CreateProcess = 0x000000080,
    SetQuota = 0x00000100,
    SetInformation = 0x00000200,
    QueryInformation = 0x00000400,
    QueryLimitedInformation = 0x00001000,
    Synchronize = 0x00100000
}

[Flags]
public enum AllocationType
{
    Commit = 0x1000,
    Reserve = 0x2000,
    Reset = 0x80000,
    TopDown = 0x100000,
    WriteWatch = 0x200000,
    Physical = 0x400000,
    LargePages = 0x20000000
}

[Flags]
public enum MemoryProtection
{
    NoAccess = 0x01,
    ReadOnly = 0x02,
    ReadWrite = 0x04,
    WriteCopy = 0x08,
    Execute = 0x10,
    ExecuteRead = 0x20,
    ExecuteReadWrite = 0x40,
    ExecuteWriteCopy = 0x80,
    Guard = 0x100,
    NoCache = 0x200,
    WriteCombine = 0x400
}
```

}`

This is the injection code, and this gets the process id:

`

```
        using System; using System.Collections.Generic; using System.Diagnostics; using System.Linq; using System.Text; using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestUI { public static class ProcessHelpers { public static int GetProcessIdByName(string processName) { var processes = Process.GetProcessesByName(processName);

if (processes.Length == 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"Could not find process with name '{processName}'");
        }

        // Return the ID of the first matching process
        return processes[0].Id;
    }
}
```

}
`

And this is how i call it after a button press:

`

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
string processName = "notepad"; string dllPath; int processId = ProcessHelpers.GetProcessIdByName("notepad");
OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();

        openFileDialog.Filter = "DLL files (*.dll)|*.dll";

        if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            dllPath = openFileDialog.FileName;

            DllInjector injector = new DllInjector();
            if (injector.InjectDll(processName, processId, dllPath))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Injection successful");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Injection failed");
            }
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
}`
```

The return is true, and i get the messagebox saying that it was sucessful, but the menu does not show up. Can anyone help me?

I expected the menu to show up. I also have a hotkey for it `INS`, this open and closes the menu. I used Dear ImGui.
The code i inserted here was messed up by the site, but it is readable

Comment: `I expected the menu to show up` - what menu? where is that defined?

Comment: the imgui menu, the menu that allows me to change colors. I downloaded it from the internet, and made some ajustments

Comment: After `WaitForSingleObject` call `GetExitCodeThread`

Comment: Also, you're leaking a thread handle because you never called `CloseHandle` on it.

Comment: "Note that CreateRemoteThread may succeed even if lpStartAddress points to data, code, or is not accessible. If the start address is invalid when the thread runs, an exception occurs, and the thread terminates."  But your program will display "Injection successful" anyway.

Comment: As to why injection fails, a very likely possibility is mismatched architecture (32-bit vs 64-bit) between injector and victim.